# React tests are passing with incorrect props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-testing-library

We have bootstrapped a create react app project using typescript and use react-testing-library for our unit tests.

We have noticed that, as we have updated our props and types, tests are still running and passing which is very worrying indeed.

As an example, we have a className which is a typescript DU. The test is using an unexpected value for className which this screen shot shows:

[image: typescript error on hover]

But the test still runs and show as as successful. If I open the VS CODE problems tab, it correctly shows as an issue:

[image: vs code problems tab]

The question is, why is the test still building and passing, is extra configuration needed to get typescript errors to work with jest/react-testing-library?

I would like these errors to prevent tests from running in the first instance to highlight an issue with props.

This is just one example, we have other tests were required props are completely missing yet the tests still run and pass

Applies to react-scripts 3.4.1 and 4.0

A colleague has kindly but together an example repo on [github](https://github.com/chrissysemens/test-project)

Comment: Can you add a sample test that was passing even though it has incorrect data?

Comment: we are about to bootstrap a new project now to try and reproduce, want to make sure we haven't broken something! Will upload once ready.

Comment: demo repo added, link is in the question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run the TypeScript compiler to check the types before running the tests. For example, update the "test" script in `package.json` to:

```json
"test": "tsc --noEmit && react-scripts test",
```

Comment: ah thank you, any idea why this is not enabled by default or why npm start picks up the errors?

Comment: @Phil Based on the discussion in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5626 this is a known limitation. The "start" and "build" scripts run the TypeScript compiler, but Create React App's configuration doesn't currently type check when running the tests.